# Валидация CA TLS/SSL сертификата

Tags: x509certificate

Я получил сертификат от Let's Encrypt. У меня есть домен-chain.pem, домент-chain-only.pem, домен-crt.pem, домен-key.pem. Как я понял key.pem - закрытый ключ, crt.pem - открытый. У меня вопрос как мне будь я браузером проверить что мой crt.pem принадлежит реально мне, я прочитал что браузер имеет набор root сертификатов и с их помощью проверяет, как?

Comment: @PakUula вот мне интересно где получить публичный ключ Let's Encrypt X3 и как самому проверить соответствие

Comment: ключ вроде нашел, теперь интересно что и как делает браузер

Comment: Тут надо сперва определиться, что именно проверяем. Если «crt.pem принадлежит реально мне», то владение закрытым ключом и способность писать/читать зашифрованные сообщения будет являться доказательством владения сертификатом, и центр сертификации здесь не нужен (это если очень упрощённо)

Comment: @andreymal не, я свой закрытый вообще не смотрю, знаю что он может расшифровывать то что зашифровано с помощью публичного, браузер же получает от меня публичный и имеет ключ от CA, как он проверяет что мой публичный принадлежит мне? как из моего публичного знает что он Lets Encrypt а не другой?

Comment: Сообщение шифруется публичным ключом, и если вы его сможете расшифровать своим приватным (ассимметричное шифрование, вот это вот всё), то значит публичный ключ и вправду принадлежит вам. (Опять же очень упрощённо, за годы эволюции алгоритмы сильно усложнились, об этом лучше какую-нибудь умную книжку по криптографии почитать)

Comment: В современном TLS всё довольно мудрёно, владение сертификатом проверяется через подписи, которые попутно создаются в процессе установки соединения. Не знаю, как это кратко и понятно описать в комментарии, но например тут довольно подробное расписывание работы TLS https://tls.dxdt.ru/tls.html

Answer (score 1):

Ваш сертификат подписан приватным ключом удостоверяющего центра "Let's Encrypt Authority  X3". Сертификат этого удостоверяющего центра хранится в браузере (или в операционной системе, в случае Windows и MacOS).
Браузер проверяет, что

1. цифровая подпись соответствует публичному ключу сертификата "Let's Encrypt Authority X3"
2. текущее время укладывается в допустимый диапазон для сертификата, т.е. между отсечками времени в полях not-valid-before, not-valid-after
3. Назначение сертификата - удостоверение сайта (Значение TLS_WEB_SERVER_AUTHENTICATION в поле Extended Key Usage)
4. доменное имя сервера соответствует значению в полях Subject Name или Alternative Subject Name
5. Браузер может также обратиться к удостоверяющему центру с запросом, не отозван ли сертификат сервера.

Кроме того, в ходе TLS Handshake браузер просит, чтобы сервер подписал случайную строку своим приватным ключом, и проверяет эту цифровую подпись публичным ключом из сертификата сервера. Это необходимо для доказательства владения приватным ключом, соответствующим сертификату.

## Как проверить сертификат самому

Команда `openssl verify` проверяет базовые свойства сертификата (1 и 2 в предыдущем списке)

Вам нужны оба сертификата проекта Let's Encrypt: [корневой isrgrootx1.pem](https://letsencrypt.org/certs/isrgrootx1.pem) и промежуточный [Certificate Authority X3 letsencryptauthorityx3.pem](https://letsencrypt.org/certs/letsencryptauthorityx3.pem)

Команда для проверки:

```
sudo openssl verify -CAfile isrgrootx1.pem -untrusted letsencryptauthorityx3.pem домен-crt.pem
```